# Basic Use of ApplyImpulse

Tags: javascript, box2d

I am trying to apply a force to a bunch of b2_dynamicBodys, but it seems to only work for a random number of items and then stops with an error.

```
     //create some items to move
     bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
     for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
        fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(1,1);
        fixDef.friction = 1;
        fixDef.restitution = .1;
        bodyDef.position.x = Math.random() * 10;
        bodyDef.position.y = Math.random() * 10;
        bodyDef.linearDamping=1;
        bodyDef.angularDamping=.8;
        itemsArray.push(world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef));  // store for later
     }
```

then i try to apply a force later with:

```
angle = 20;
for (var xIdx=0; xIdx<itemArray.length; xIdx++) {
    itemsArray[xIdx].GetBody().ApplyImpulse(new b2Vec2(50*Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180),50*Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)););
}
```

the error I receive is

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.x')
```

Is there something wrong with saving the items for later use when I am creating them?  Does anyone know what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is diceArray.length used in this code:

```
for (var xIdx=0; xIdx<diceArray.length; xIdx++) {
```

the same as itemsArray.length when referencing itemsArray in the same loop?

```
itemsArray[xIdx].GetBody()....
```

So, itemsArray size is definitely 5, is diceArray size 5 too?

Edited now jfiddle source given:
ApplyImpulse requires 2 parameters and you are only passing in 1.

I added {x:200,y:200} and all is fine

```
diceArray[xIdx].GetBody().ApplyImpulse(actionVec, {x:200,y:200});
```

Comment: sorry typo, yes they are the same. I renamed the array. http://jsfiddle.net/nycynik/LGq63/

Comment: after adding that fiddle, i think i see that it never works, its not random at all.

Comment: See edit above for solution

Comment: Oh!  Yes it does
public function ApplyImpulse(impulse:b2Vec2,point:b2Vec2):voidParameters
The point is the origin of the force.
 Thank you!